# How can I retrieve a specific text node (first, or second, or last) from my xml when my xml has mulitple text nodes using SQL Server 2017?

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, xquery

/* How can I retrieve a specific text node (first, or second, or last) from my xml when my xml has mulitple text nodes?

In this example I have a varchar(max) column named ExtraData, containing a xml string, in my table sdcdev.dbo.ProductConfiguration. My SQL casts the ExtraData varchar into a xml data type during the table join.  I am joining 2 records, have 1 SDC.Application.Master record for LegacyProductID = 51965464 AND LegacyProdConfigID = 109 and 1 matching sdcdev.dbo.ProductConfiguration for ProductID = 51965464 AND ProdConfigID = 109 containing the xml string wwith a 1-to-many relationship within. The goal is to retrieve a specific node from the 7 matching nodes in the 1-to-many relationshiip within the xml string. I extracted the 1-to-many xml portion here for review: */

```
USE [SDCDEV]
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ProductConfiguration](
    [ProductID] int NOT NULL,
    [ProdConfigID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ExtraData] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [CreatedByUserID] int NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedByUserID] int NULL,
    [CreatedOn] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedOn] [datetime] NULL,
    [IsActiveFlag] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_ProductConfiguration] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ProductID] ASC,
    [ProdConfigID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 100) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]
GO

USE [SDCDEV]
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ProductConfiguration]
           ([ProductID]
           ,[ProdConfigID]
           ,[ExtraData]
           ,[CreatedByUserID]
           ,[UpdatedByUserID]
           ,[CreatedOn]
           ,[UpdatedOn]
           ,[IsActiveFlag])
     VALUES
           (51965464
           ,109
           ,'<App action="A" id="2062"><BaseVehicle id="2318" /><EngineBase id="1253" /><MfrLabel>Hi-Performance</MfrLabel><Note>255 lph</Note><Part>GCA70704</Part><PartType id="6256" /><Qty>1</Qty><Qual id="8123"><param value="5003860AA" /><text>Replaces OE Part Number(s) 5003860AA</text></Qual><Qual id="8123"><param value="5003860AB" /><text>Replaces OE Part Number(s) 5003860AB</text></Qual><Qual id="8123"><param value="5003861AA" /><text>Replaces OE Part Number(s) 5003861AA</text></Qual><Qual id="8123"><param value="5003861AB" /><text>Replaces OE Part Number(s) 5003861AB</text></Qual><Qual id="8123"><param value="52018390" /><text>Replaces OE Part Number(s) 52018390</text></Qual><Qual id="8123"><param value="52018391" /><text>Replaces OE Part Number(s) 52018391</text></Qual><Qual id="5233"><text>High Pressure</text></Qual></App>'
           ,5393
           ,NULL
           ,'2020-02-20 10:53:45.957'
           ,NULL
           ,1)
GO

USE [SDCDEV]
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[ApplicationMaster](
    [ApplicationID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProductID] [int] NULL,
    [AspirationID] [int] NULL,
    [AssetItemOrder] [int] NULL,
    [AssetItemRef] [int] NULL,
    [AssetName] [varchar](450) NULL,
    [BaseVehicleID] [int] NULL,
    [BedLengthID] [int] NULL,
    [BedTypeID] [int] NULL,
    [BodyNumDoorsID] [int] NULL,
    [BodyTypeID] [int] NULL,
    [BrakeABSID] [int] NULL,
    [BrakeSystemID] [int] NULL,
    [CylinderHeadTypeID] [int] NULL,
    [DisplayOrder] [int] NULL,
    [DriveTypeID] [int] NULL,
    [EngineBaseID] [int] NULL,
    [EngineBlockID] [int] NULL,
    [EngineBoreStrokeID] [int] NULL,
    [EngineDesignationID] [int] NULL,
    [EngineMfrID] [int] NULL,
    [EngineVersionID] [int] NULL,
    [EngineVINID] [int] NULL,
    [EquipmentBaseID] [int] NULL,
    [EquipmentModelID] [int] NULL,
    [FrontBrakeTypeID] [int] NULL,
    [FrontSpringTypeID] [int] NULL,
    [FuelDeliverySubTypeID] [int] NULL,
    [FuelDeliveryTypeID] [int] NULL,
    [FuelSystemControlTypeID] [int] NULL,
    [FuelSystemDesignID] [int] NULL,
    [FuelTypeID] [int] NULL,
    [IgnitionSystemTypeID] [int] NULL,
    [MakeID] [int] NULL,
    [MfrBodyCodeID] [int] NULL,
    [MfrLabel] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [ModelID] [int] NULL,
    [Note] [varchar](1000) NULL,
    [PartNumber] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [PartType] [int] NULL,
    [Position] [int] NULL,
    [PowerOutputID] [int] NULL,
    [Qty] [int] NULL,
    [RearBrakeTypeID] [int] NULL,
    [RearSpringTypeID] [int] NULL,
    [RegionID] [int] NULL,
    [SteeringSystemID] [int] NULL,
    [SteeringTypeID] [int] NULL,
    [SubModelID] [int] NULL,
    [TransElecControlledID] [int] NULL,
    [TransferDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [TransmissionBaseID] [int] NULL,
    [TransmissionControlTypeID] [int] NULL,
    [TransmissionMfrCodeID] [int] NULL,
    [TransmissionMfrID] [int] NULL,
    [TransmissionNumSpeedsID] [int] NULL,
    [TransmissionTypeID] [int] NULL,
    [ValvesID] [int] NULL,
    [VehicleTypeID] [int] NULL,
    [WheelBaseID] [int] NULL,
    [YearFromID] [int] NULL,
    [YearToID] [int] NULL,
    [CreatedByUserID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedByUserID] [int] NULL,
    [IsActiveFlag] [tinyint] NOT NULL,
    [CreatedOn] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedOn] [datetime] NULL,
    [LegacyProductID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [LegacyProdConfigID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [MaintenanceType] [char](1) NULL,
    [YearID] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Application] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ApplicationID] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON, FILLFACTOR = 100) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] 
GO

USE [SDCDEV]
GO
INSERT INTO [dbo].[ApplicationMaster]
           ([ApplicationID]
           ,[ProductID]
           ,[AspirationID]
           ,[AssetItemOrder]
           ,[AssetItemRef]
           ,[AssetName]
           ,[BaseVehicleID]
           ,[BedLengthID]
           ,[BedTypeID]
           ,[BodyNumDoorsID]
           ,[BodyTypeID]
           ,[BrakeABSID]
           ,[BrakeSystemID]
           ,[CylinderHeadTypeID]
           ,[DisplayOrder]
           ,[DriveTypeID]
           ,[EngineBaseID]
           ,[EngineBlockID]
           ,[EngineBoreStrokeID]
           ,[EngineDesignationID]
           ,[EngineMfrID]
           ,[EngineVersionID]
           ,[EngineVINID]
           ,[EquipmentBaseID]
           ,[EquipmentModelID]
           ,[FrontBrakeTypeID]
           ,[FrontSpringTypeID]
           ,[FuelDeliverySubTypeID]
           ,[FuelDeliveryTypeID]
           ,[FuelSystemControlTypeID]
           ,[FuelSystemDesignID]
           ,[FuelTypeID]
           ,[IgnitionSystemTypeID]
           ,[MakeID]
           ,[MfrBodyCodeID]
           ,[MfrLabel]
           ,[ModelID]
           ,[Note]
           ,[PartNumber]
           ,[PartType]
           ,[Position]
           ,[PowerOutputID]
           ,[Qty]
           ,[RearBrakeTypeID]
           ,[RearSpringTypeID]
           ,[RegionID]
           ,[SteeringSystemID]
           ,[SteeringTypeID]
           ,[SubModelID]
           ,[TransElecControlledID]
           ,[TransferDate]
           ,[TransmissionBaseID]
           ,[TransmissionControlTypeID]
           ,[TransmissionMfrCodeID]
           ,[TransmissionMfrID]
           ,[TransmissionNumSpeedsID]
           ,[TransmissionTypeID]
           ,[ValvesID]
           ,[VehicleTypeID]
           ,[WheelBaseID]
           ,[YearFromID]
           ,[YearToID]
           ,[CreatedByUserID]
           ,[UpdatedByUserID]
           ,[IsActiveFlag]
           ,[CreatedOn]
           ,[UpdatedOn]
           ,[LegacyProductID]
           ,[LegacyProdConfigID]
           ,[MaintenanceType]
           ,[YearID])
     VALUES
           (132831307
           ,5381240
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,2318
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,1253
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,'Hi-Performance'
           ,NULL
           ,'255 lph'
           ,'GCA70704'
           ,6256
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,1
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,NULL
           ,5393
           ,NULL
           ,1
           ,'2020-02-20 10:53:45.957'
           ,NULL
           ,51965464
           ,109
           ,'A'
           ,NULL)
GO


SELECT a.ApplicationID AS ApplicationID, a.LegacyProductID AS LegacyProductID, a.LegacyProdConfigID AS LegacyProdConfigID
FROM SDCDEV.dbo.ApplicationMaster a (NOLOCK)
WHERE a.LegacyProductID = 51965464 AND a.LegacyProdConfigID = 109
ORDER BY a.ApplicationID
```

--Returns: GOOD
--ApplicationID LegacyProductID LegacyProdConfigID
--132831307 51965464    109

```
SELECT pc.ProductID,pc.ProdConfigID,ExtraData = cast(pc.ExtraData as xml)
FROM sdcdev.dbo.ProductConfiguration pc (NOLOCK)
WHERE pc.ProductID = 51965464
AND pc.ProdConfigID = 109
```

--Returns: GOOD
--ProductID ProdConfigID    ExtraData
--51965464  109 Hi-Performance255 lphGCA707041Replaces OE Part Number(s) 5003860AAReplaces OE Part Number(s) 5003860ABReplaces OE Part Number(s) 5003861AAReplaces OE Part Number(s) 5003861ABReplaces OE Part Number(s) 52018390Replaces OE Part Number(s) 52018391High Pressure

```
SELECT a.ApplicationID AS ApplicationID
    ,X.Y.value('(/App/Qual/@id)[1]', 'varchar(10)') AS QDBQualifierID
    ,1 AS TextIndex
    ,X.Y.value('(text)[1]','varchar(100)') AS TextValue
    ,a.LegacyProductID AS LegacyProductID
    ,a.LegacyProdConfigID AS LegacyProdConfigID
    ,vpc.ExtraData.query('/App/Qual') AS LegacyQualifierXML
FROM SDCDEV.dbo.ApplicationMaster a (NOLOCK)
join (select pc.ProductID,pc.ProdConfigID,ExtraData = cast(pc.ExtraData as xml)
        from sdcdev.dbo.ProductConfiguration pc (NOLOCK)
        WHERE pc.ProductID = 51965464
        AND pc.ProdConfigID = 109
        ) vpc on vpc.ProductID = a.LegacyProductID and vpc.ProdConfigID = a.LegacyProdConfigID
OUTER APPLY vpc.ExtraData.nodes('App/Qual') AS X(Y)
WHERE X.Y.value('(/App/Qual/@id)[1]', 'varchar(10)') IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY a.ApplicationID
```

--Returns: BAD RESULTS

/*
HOW DO I GET THE TEXT (,X.Y.value('(text)[1]','varchar(100)') AS TextValue) FOR JUST THE 1ST QUAL ID (X.Y.value('(/App/Qual/@id)[1]', 'varchar(10)') AS QDBQualifierID)
I wanted only the 1st Qual Id text only, not all 7 text values with the incorrect 1st Qual ID
Returns: the 1st Qual ID repeated for all 7 rows, then a row for wach text.
ApplicationID    QDBQualifierID    TextIndex    TextValue                                                LegacyProductID    LegacyProdConfigID
132831307      8123                  1                Replaces OE Part Number(s) 5003860AA     51965464              109
132831307      8123                  1                Replaces OE Part Number(s) 5003860AB     51965464              109
132831307      8123                  1                Replaces OE Part Number(s) 5003861AA     51965464              109
132831307      8123                  1                Replaces OE Part Number(s) 5003861AB     51965464              109
132831307      8123                  1                Replaces OE Part Number(s) 52018390      51965464              109
132831307      8123                  1                Replaces OE Part Number(s) 52018391      51965464              109
132831307      8123                  1                High Pressure                            51965464              109

HOW DO I GET THE TEXT (,X.Y.value('(text)[1]','varchar(100)') AS TextValue) FOR JUST THE 1ST QUAL ID (X.Y.value('(/App/Qual/@id)[1]', 'varchar(10)') AS QDBQualifierID)?
I wanted just the 1st row.
ApplicationID    QDBQualifierID    TextIndex    TextValue                                                LegacyProductID    LegacyProdConfigID
132831307      8123                  1                Replaces OE Part Number(s) 5003860AA     51965464              109

HOW DO I GET THE LAST (7) TEXT (,X.Y.value('(text)[1]','varchar(100)') AS TextValue) FOR JUST THE 7th QUAL ID (X.Y.value('(/App/Qual/@id)[7]', 'varchar(10)') AS QDBQualifierID)?
or just the 7 row if I used  X.Y.value('(/App/Qual/@id)[7] instead.
ApplicationID    QDBQualifierID    TextIndex    TextValue                                                LegacyProductID    LegacyProdConfigID
132831307      5233                  7                High Pressure                                          51965464              109

HOW DO I GET ALL (7) TEXT ROWS WITH QUAL ID AND TEXT MATCHING CORRECTLY?
Or all 7 rows returned correctly:
ApplicationID    QDBQualifierID    TextIndex    TextValue                                                LegacyProductID    LegacyProdConfigID
132831307      8123                  1                Replaces OE Part Number(s) 5003860AA     51965464              109
132831307      8124                  2                Replaces OE Part Number(s) 5003860AB     51965464              109
132831307      8125                  3                Replaces OE Part Number(s) 5003861AA     51965464              109
132831307      8126                  4                Replaces OE Part Number(s) 5003861AB     51965464              109
132831307      8127                  5                Replaces OE Part Number(s) 52018390       51965464              109
132831307      8128                  6                Replaces OE Part Number(s) 52018391       51965464              109
132831307      5233                  7                High Pressure                                          51965464              109
*/

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example for you.

The XML sample has seven `<Qual>` elements. You can control which one(s) you need via XPath predicate by using SQL Server `@seq` variable, and beyond.

I provided three scenarios below. Check  it out.

**SQL**

```
-- DDL and sample data population, start
DECLARE @ProductConfiguration TABLE (
    [ProductID] int NOT NULL,
    [ProdConfigID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ExtraData] [varchar](max) NULL,
    [CreatedByUserID] int NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedByUserID] int NULL,
    [CreatedOn] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [UpdatedOn] [datetime] NULL,
    [IsActiveFlag] [tinyint] NOT NULL
);
INSERT INTO @ProductConfiguration
    ([ProductID]
    ,[ProdConfigID]
    ,[ExtraData]
    ,[CreatedByUserID]
    ,[UpdatedByUserID]
    ,[CreatedOn]
    ,[UpdatedOn]
    ,[IsActiveFlag]) VALUES
(51965464, 109
, N'<App action="A" id="2062">
    <BaseVehicle id="2318"/>
    <EngineBase id="1253"/>
    <MfrLabel>Hi-Performance</MfrLabel>
    <Note>255 lph</Note>
    <Part>GCA70704</Part>
    <PartType id="6256"/>
    <Qty>1</Qty>
    <Qual id="8123">
        <param value="5003860AA"/>
        <text>Replaces OE Part Number(s) 5003860AA</text>
    </Qual>
    <Qual id="8123">
        <param value="5003860AB"/>
        <text>Replaces OE Part Number(s) 5003860AB</text>
    </Qual>
    <Qual id="8123">
        <param value="5003861AA"/>
        <text>Replaces OE Part Number(s) 5003861AA</text>
    </Qual>
    <Qual id="8123">
        <param value="5003861AB"/>
        <text>Replaces OE Part Number(s) 5003861AB</text>
    </Qual>
    <Qual id="8123">
        <param value="52018390"/>
        <text>Replaces OE Part Number(s) 52018390</text>
    </Qual>
    <Qual id="8123">
        <param value="52018391"/>
        <text>Replaces OE Part Number(s) 52018391</text>
    </Qual>
    <Qual id="5233">
        <text>High Pressure</text>
    </Qual>
</App>'
,5393 , NULL, '2020-02-20 10:53:45.957', NULL, 1);
-- DDL and sample data population, end

DECLARE @seq INT = 1;

;WITH rs AS
(
    SELECT ProductID
        , ProdConfigID
        , ExtraData = TRY_CAST(ExtraData AS XML)
    FROM @ProductConfiguration
    WHERE ProductID = 51965464
    AND ProdConfigID = 109
)
SELECT ProductID, ProdConfigID
    , c.value('(param/@value)[1]','VARCHAR(10)') AS [param]
    , c.value('(text/text())[1]','VARCHAR(100)') AS [text]
FROM rs
    OUTER APPLY ExtraData.nodes('/App/Qual[sql:variable("@seq")]') AS t(c);
```

**Output**

```
+-----------+--------------+-----------+--------------------------------------+
| ProductID | ProdConfigID |   param   |                 text                 |
+-----------+--------------+-----------+--------------------------------------+
|  51965464 |          109 | 5003860AA | Replaces OE Part Number(s) 5003860AA |
+-----------+--------------+-----------+--------------------------------------+
```

**Last**

```
...
OUTER APPLY ExtraData.nodes('/App/Qual[last()]') AS t(c);
```

**Any sequence (1st, 2nd, 5th)**

```
...
OUTER APPLY ExtraData.nodes('/App/Qual[position()=(1,2,5)]') AS t(c);
```